# HTML5 Moving Objects

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I've read many posts and gone through several tutorials on HTML5 and the canvas specifically, but so far I have been unable to replicate my exact problem. If there is an answer for it already out there, please point me in the right direction.

My ultimate goal is to make a simple Pong game. I've drawn the basic objects using JavaScript and now I am trying to get the player (left) paddle to move. The problem I am running into with my current code is that instead of moving the paddle, it fills in the area it travels to. Through various trials and error of adapting and trying different methods I don't think the paddle is being elongated (adding pixels to the height), but it seems like a new paddle object is being created rather than the one being moved.

I've looked it over and over again (you guys aren't a first-ditch effort), but can't seem to figure out what's happening. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
// Requests a callback 60 times per second from browser
var animate = window.requestAnimationFrame ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
        window.oRequestAnimationFrame      ||
        window.msRequestAnimationFrame     ||
    function(callback) { window.setTimeout(callback, 1000/60) };

// Get canvas and set context
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

context.fillStyle = "white";

// Settle variables for canvas width and height
var canvas_width = 500;
var canvas_height = 400;

// Set varaibles for paddle width and height
var paddle_width = 15;
var paddle_height = 75;

// Initializes variables
var playerScore = 0;
var computerScore = 0;
var player = new Player();
var computer = new Computer();
var ball = new Ball((canvas_width/2),(canvas_height/2));

// Renders the pong table
var render = function() {
  player.render();
  computer.render();
  ball.render();
};

var update = function() {
  player.update();
};

// Callback for animate function
var step = function() {
  update();
  render();
  animate(step);
};

// Creates paddle object to build player and computer objects
function Paddle(x, y, width, height) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y; 
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  this.x_speed = 0;
  this.y_speed = 0;
};

function Player() {
  this.paddle = new Paddle(1, ((canvas_height/2) - (paddle_height/2)), paddle_width, paddle_height);
};

function Computer() {
  this.paddle = new Paddle((canvas_width - paddle_width - 1), ((canvas_height/2) - (paddle_height/2)), paddle_width, paddle_height);
};

// Creates ball object
function Ball(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.radius = 10;
};

// Adds render functions to objects allowing them to be drawn on canvas
Ball.prototype.render = function() {
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, Math.PI * 2, false);
  context.fillStyle = "white";
  context.fill();
  context.closePath();
};

Paddle.prototype.render = function() {
  context.fillStyle = "white";
  context.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
};

Player.prototype.render = function() {
  this.paddle.render();
};

// Appends a move method to Paddle prototype
Paddle.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
  this.y += y;
  this.y_speed = y;
};

// Updates the location of the player paddle
Player.prototype.update = function() {
  for(var key in keysDown) {
    var value = Number(key);
    if(value == 38) {
      this.paddle.move(0, -4);
    } else if (value == 40) {
      this.paddle.move(0, 4);
    } else {
      this.paddle.move(0, 0);
    }
  }
};

Computer.prototype.render = function() {
  this.paddle.render();
};

// Draws center diving line
context.strokeStyle = "white";
context.setLineDash([5, 3]);
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo((canvas_width/2), 0);
context.lineTo((canvas_width/2), canvas_height);
context.stroke();
context.closePath();

// Draws score on canvas
context.font = "40px Arial";
context.fillText('0', (canvas_width * .23), 50);
context.fillText('0', (canvas_width * .73), 50);

window.onload = function() {
  animate(step);
};

var keysDown = {};

window.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  keysDown[event.keyCode] = true;
});

window.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  delete keysDown[event.keyCode];
});
```

My apologies: I cut the html/css code and meant to paste it, but forgot.

pong.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Pong</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="400"></canvas>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

style.css:

```
#canvas {
  background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canvas itself has no "objects", it's just a bitmap, and anything you draw on it just changes the colours of certain pixels, making it look like it's drawing "on top" of what's already there but it doesn't even do that. It just flips pixel colours.

I don't see any code that "resets" the canvas for your next frames, so you're literally just drawing the same paddle at a different height value by colouring different pixels with the paddle's colours without recolouring the original pixels using the background colour.

The easiest solution here is to add a `context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);`  at the start of `render()`:

```
var render = function() {
  // clear the canvas so we can draw a new frame
  context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  // draw the frame content to the bitmap
  player.render();
  computer.render();
  ball.render();
};
```

Note that this reveals you also need to draw your scores and center line every frame. Either that, or you need to make sure your paddles (and your ball) first restore the background colour on their old position, before drawing themselves on their new position, which would require considerably more code.

Comment: Ahh, thank you! That certainly did it. I greatly appreciate the explanation beforehand. That clears up a couple questions I had, actually, and gave me a better understanding of the canvas. I was going to ask about the center dividing line and text, but you already answered that! Thank you, sir! =)